# SMS on iPad. Doesn't see popup

Tags: iphone, ipad, sms

I would like to activate SMS on my iPad but when I go on my iPhone, this one tell me to enter a code which appears on the iPad.

But I have no popup on my iPad.

I have the same iCloud account on both devices and activate FaceTime.

Why I don't see this popup ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one thing to try, from [MacRumors](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/10/21/test-message-forwarding-no-code/):

> ...you need to have your email address turned on for iMessage on your iPhone in order to enable Text Message Forwarding. If you don't, the numeric access code will not appear on your iPad or Mac during the setup process.
>
> As soon as you enable your email address for iMessage (you only need to do this on your iPhone) the numeric access codes appear as expected. Once you have text message forwarding setup you can disable your email address again in iMessage as it seems to only be necessary for the numeric access code setup step, not the actual text message forwarding itself.

Comment: I have already an email address configured for iMessage but no popup

Comment: Try signing out of messages on iPhone and iPad, waiting 15 minutes, then signing back in on both.

Comment: Not working better :(